# Вывод массива слов в строку через запятую JAVA

Tags: java

Как осуществить вывод слов через запятую? Есть вариант создать StringBuilder, записать в него "word_from_array" + ",". И потом удалить лишнюю запятую в конце. Но может есть какой-то красивый способ это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
String result = String.join(",", container);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/9fXTJT

Ну или используйте [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), которым `String.join` пользуется внутри:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for (String s : container)
    joiner.add(s);
String result = joiner.toString();
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/myQarW

Если вы пользуетесь Stream API, подойдёт ещё [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).